# how to go back to some position already printed in C?

Tags: c, printf, textcolor

let us have a situation in which the following program prints some 10 lines of #

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
prinf("\n#");
```

now how to go back to 5 th line and edit that # and change the color of it without clearing the screen or clearing the below 5 lines?

I have tried

```
window(5,0,20,20);
textcolor(GREEN);
cprintf("#");
```

but it is not editing that one but it is printing on the side of the original one.why?

is there any other way of doing it and changing the color of the already printed text dynamically?
please help me..my environment is turbo c on windows

Comment: Probably because it reads very much like a homework problem.  Whether it is or not, that's the impression that's given.

Comment: well its not a home work question i m trying to develop a game on basic C without graphics.h

Comment: @Tim , so you are saying homework questions are not allowed , even though they are related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window function will generally create a window from the 1st two coordinates pixel i.e, in your example (5,0) to the pixel pointed by next 2 coordinates. so your program should work

try it out or else use gotoxy()

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are mixing printf and another output library - this isn't recommended.  Printf expects to be sent to a character terminal, while the output library in question may falsly assume that it has exclusive access (and might misbehave.)

Based on one function, you're likely using conio.h.  The documentation can be found [here](http://poli.cs.vsb.cz/c/help/conio.htm), with a table of contents showing each available function.  From that index, you should be able to spot the function instantly.

The window function doesn't do what you want it to, since it only sets the area in which the cursor may change text - it doesn't move the cursor, you need to use the other library functions.

Answer (score 1):

`-1:`  Some tips for posting homework questions:

1) Get the question right!  The posted code does not perform as the description states:

```
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    prinf("#");
```

This will print 10 `#` characters on one line, as there is no end-of-line character.  The original description talks about "printing 10 lines."

2) Give necessary details: What environment are you using: Windows?  Linux?  What compiler?  Is this a windowed or text-based environment?

3) STFW before posting. Look for "ANSI Escape Sequences" or "positioning the cursor."

Answer (score 0):

maybe-

```
cprintf("\b#");
```

'b' is for backspace